# Binding a System.Drawing.Image to a Gridview in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, gridview

I have defined a gridview control with a column of type `ImageField` and I bind the gridview to a `List<MyRecord>`.

MyRecord includes a property of type `System.Drawing.Image`, but the image is not rendered in the gridview.

There are numerous articles re binding using the URL field which points to (say) a jpg file... but i have the actual Image, not a file.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a custom ImageHandler like this article describes:

[Image Handling In ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126421/Image-Handling-In-ASP-NET)

Comment: thanks.. I implemented a custom ImagHandler and I now see the entire column of the gridview having identical images.  However, I have a List<> of images and am unclear how to get the Handler called to return an image for each row.   Perhaps I have to construct a temporary SQL database and bind the gridview to that.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the ImageField works. It expects the URL to the image.

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField = "ImageUrl" ...
```

Comment: URLs normally point to files, like pic.jpg..... but in this case, you can have it point to a Handler page, Handler.ashx, which is compiled to accept the URL request and return an image without ever having it stored in a file.

Answer (score 0):

The Handler.ashx worked... thank you

in the code, i set the `ImageUrl = string.Format("~/HandlerGetImage.ashx?id={0}", imageNumber);`

This dynamically calls the Handler in which i get the image index by

```
string v = context.Request.QueryString["id"];
```

Then, the following returns the image:

```
   int ix = Convert.ToInt32(v);
   MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Query.imageList[ix]); // imagelist is created elsewhere
   System.Drawing.Image returnImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);

   context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

   //saving bitmap image
   returnImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream,
   System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
   returnImage.Dispose();
```